# Can't select value in combo box using Coded UI Test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

```
        WinComboBox comboxBox = new WinComboBox();  
        comboxBox.SearchProperties[WinComboBox.PropertyNames.Name] = "Server:";
        comboxBox.WindowTitles.Add("Server Settings");
        comboxBox.SearchProperties[WinComboBox.PropertyNames.TechnologyName] = "Server";
        comboxBox.SearchProperties[WinComboBox.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "comboBoxPlatforms";
        comboxBox.SelectedItem = "Value3";
```

I used above code for selecting a value in a combo box using Coded UI test.

But I am getting the error

> System.NotSupportedException: GetProperty of "SelectedItem" is not supported on control type: Window

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or show me an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i add this : comboxBox.TechnologyName = “MSAA”;

I think WindowTitles is not needed.

Try also 
Mouse.click (comboBox) and playback.wait(1000); above  comboxBox.SelectedItem = "Value3"; To exclude some common problems. If that solves your issue then you can start refactoring.

Ik hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception points out, the UITestControl object you have is of ControlType `WINDOW`, which is why you are not able to do SetProperty on it.

I will specify parent control also while searching.

```
WinComboBox comboxBox = new WinComboBox(WinWIndow Parent);
```

If your control is WinCombobox try:

```
combobox.SetProperty("SelectedItem", "Value3");
```

Also If you know the index of the item try:

```
combobox.SetProperty("SelectedIndex", 3);
```

Let me know if it resolves your issue